# what is a pre class error in cakephp3

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

In cakephp3 I keep getting an error message in the title of the webpage on the tab.

I am adding some data to a table and thats all and it works fine so what with this error message and how can i get rid of it?

I cant copy and paste the error but I get the same sort of thing as this webpage  http://www.huntnhire.com/DegreeSpecializations/getByDegree

```
 public function adddisplay()
    {

         $subjects = $this->Subjects->find()

              ->order(['Subjects.name' => 'ASC'])
              ->hydrate(true);

        $subject = $this->Subjects->newEntity();
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $subject = $this->Subjects->patchEntity($subject, $this->request->data);
            if ($this->Subjects->save($subject)) {
                $this->Flash->success(__('The subject has been saved.'));
                return $this->redirect(['action' => 'adddisplay']);
            } else {
                $this->Flash->error(__('The subject could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
            }
        }
        $this->set(compact('subjects'));
       // $this->set('_serialize', ['subject']);
    }
```

Comment: It might be a smart move to start by reading the error message and just fixing it to make the error go away? This is a *very* simple every days php problem. If you can't solve this you might want to start by learning the basics of reading and understanding and handling errors. This will make your programmers live a lot more easy. Also the error can be copied and pasted: You just need to inspect the page... Hit F12 in your browser.

Comment: This is an error in cakephp3 that appears oh the title of the tab in the browser . If I could fix it then I would not be here. It is a javascript onclick error which is imported in. Other people have the same error so it must be  setup issue. please respond in a more  meaningful way